# nginx map multiple endpoint to one location

Tags: nginx, flask

I have this conf:

```
location /dev/api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

/dev/api and /api should hit the same Flask API backend, when /dev/api hits, the backend pick it up as /dev/api, however, because the API is binded to /api, it returns 404. I know I can add another API resource in the backend to watch /dev/api but it is sort of duplicate.

```
class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self, share_id):
        return {'hello': 'worlds'}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/api/share/<int:share_id>', '/dev/api/share/<int:share_id>')
```

Is there a way to let nginx somehow direct /dev/api to /api and the backend pick it up as /api rather then /dev/api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is [nginx's equivalent of ProxyPassReverse](http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache):

```
  location /dev/api {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
  }
```

Also you may want to take a look at [flask's notes on the subject](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/)

NOTE: untested.